# Android ListView does not Highlight when a OnClickListener is set

Tags: android, user-interface, android-listview

I have a ListView populated with custom XML ListItems, this is the XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
                android:padding="6dip">
...
</RelativeLayout>
```

The listView shows correctly on screen and if i click or hold on an item it becomes blue (I'm using Holo Light Theme)

the problem comes when i try to assign an OnClickListener to the view, inside getView in my Activity that extends BaseAdapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ...
    convertView = InflateUtils.inflate(mContext, R.layout.list_item);
    ...
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Test", 2000).show();
        }
    });
...
}
```

after doing that, the list item highlight color is no more shown, when i click or hold on a list item it's background stays white,
anyway the onClickListener is perfectly working.

Do you have any suggestion to get the highlight color while keeping the default styles of HoloLight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to use [`OnItemClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) on the `ListView` itself, instead of separate click listeners for item views.

Also, highlight problem has already been described here: [Android listview no longer highlights selection onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085694/android-listview-no-longer-highlights-selection-onclick)

Comment: Person who downvoted, care to comment on what's wrong with my answer? That way we'll get closer to truth.

Comment: i did not, anyway i was curious about OnItemClickListener, do you think that this will solve my problem? Is there any performance issues using separates OnClickListener? - I already read that question, but the solution is not using HoloLight style, which i'm required to.

Comment: Well, if your items are alike, you can use one listener and differentiate by item id - one object instead of possibly hundreds. As for holo - you can use holo with the solution from that answer, use the highlighting background is called R.drawable.list_selector_holo_dark

Comment: Using the OnItemClickListener solves the problem, i've got less objects and my Highlight back again :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the layout attributes for the parent RelativeLayout:

```
android:addStatesFromChildren="true"
```

Alternatively, in code call:

```
convertView.setAddStatesFromChildren(true);
```

In either case, be sure that the child layouts do not have the `android:duplicateParentState` attribute set (and do not call `setDuplicateParentState(true)`), or you will get an exception at run time.

Comment: That's not working for me, the XML part. the programmatic part i can't test because compiler complains about the method setAddStatesFromChildren "Does not exist". Anyway, why it should work?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the highlighting behaviour and have multiple [`OnClickListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html), if you

1. set the `OnClickListener`
2. disable the `OnClickListener`
3. call the `OnClickListener` from an [`OnItemClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html).

To do so, add `setClickable(false)` to your code:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ...
    convertView = InflateUtils.inflate(mContext, R.layout.list_item);
    ...
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Test", 2000).show();
        }
    });
    // make non-clickable again, like before setting the OnClickListener
    convertView.setClickable(false);
    ...
}
```

and call the listener programmatically, e.g.:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle bundle)
{
   final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_with_listview, container, false);
   final ListView your_listview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.your_listview);
   // delegate to specific callbacks
   your_listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
   {   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
       {   view.callOnClick();
       }
   });
   ...
}
```

Note the documented behaviour of [`callOnClick()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#callOnClick()):

> Directly call any attached OnClickListener. Unlike [`performClick()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#performClick()), this only calls the listener, and does not do any associated clicking actions like reporting an accessibility event.